# wordpress post.php file permission become 0 in live server

Tags: wordpress, filesystems

I have used WordPress 4.7.4 , in every after two days wp-include/post.php file permission become 0 and both screen will be white.

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w12C3.png)
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions you need to follow to handle file permissions.

Change the file permissions via command line

For folders,

```
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

For files,

```
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Deny access for all user modes by editing the .htaccess file,

```
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Check all the server attributes which are affecting the files , also check the error and debug log of the server.